# Blazor how to use get requests

Tags: c#, get, blazor

Im trying to create an url shortener using Blazor.
I want the user to access an url with a get parameter which can then be used to locate the inital url and then direct him to that.
Unfortunatly i cant find anything about it.
How can i do this ?

Comment: Please show us what did you try? Source Code.